# Outer Product Definition

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

In my quantum mechanics course, the lecturer do the following definition for outer product, then equate it a matrix. Then, she want us to show this equality.
$$\sum \limits_{i}^{n}\sum \limits_{j}^{n}
\text{out}(\vec e_{i},\vec e_{j}) \equiv E_{ij}
$$

However, when I perform the calculations, I found a unit matrix as you can see from the following steps. For the sake of simplicity, I did not write the summation signs.
$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 &= \vec e_{i} \, \vec e_{j}\,^{T} \\
 &= \vec e_{i} \, \vec e_{i}\,^{T} \delta_{ij} \\
 &= \vec e_{i} \, \vec e_{i}\,^{T} \\
 &= I
\end{split}
\end{equation*}$$

I is an nxn unit matrix. I want to also mention that $e_i,e_j$ are linearly independent unit vectors.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example:
$$v = (1,2,3),\ w= (4,5,6)^\top$$
Then the outer product would be
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1*4 & 1*5 & 1*6\\
2*4 & 2*5 & 2*6 \\
3*4 & 3*5 & 3*6
\end{pmatrix} $$

Considering $e_1 =(1,0,0), e_3 = (0,0,1)$ you will get
$$E_{13} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$
$E_{13}$ is the matrix which just zeros expect at the position $(1,3)$

In general you get $1$ for the outer product of two unity vectors when $i=j$ and $0$ if $i\neq j$

Comment: But she want us to show that equality via using linearly independent unit vectors. So that's why I cannot write them explicitly.

Comment: What is $E_{ij}$ supposed to mean in the context of your question?

Comment: I have edited the answer. I guess you are talking about elemantary matrixes in your task

Comment: Thank you so much. I get it.